# ProgressDialog not showing

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

When my application first starts it needs to do some set up.  I'd like to show a progress dialog while this is happening, so the user isn't just faced with an unresponsive black screen.  I am trying to do it with the following code, but the dialog never shows:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.shell);
    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(WhereWolfActivity.this, getString(R.string.loadingtitle), getString(R.string.loading), true, false);
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(dbHelper == null)
                dbHelper = new WhereWolfOpenHelper(getApplicationContext());                    
            checkUserDetails();
            String providers = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
            checkLocationProviders(providers);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }                   
            });     
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

If I remove `dialog.dismiss();` the dialog shows up after the thread is finished.  This suggests to me that the UI thread is being blocked.  Any ideas how to fix this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine on a 2.3.3 Samsung Galaxy S i9000, I just checked (without the DB stuff, obviously - just Thread.sleep() before the runOnUIThread).

Since this answer is not very helpful, let me point you to the class [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which has been created for the task you are currently doing "by hand".

Basically, you create a subclass of AsyncTask (as an inner class of your activity) - if you don't need any parameters, just use Void,Void,Void - and start it in onCreate() with .execute();

Kick off your progress dialog in onPreExecute(), do your background work in doInBackground, and finally dismiss the dialog in onPostExecute(). No fiddling with runOnUIThread.

Comment: I tried using AsyncTask but then the app just carried on, and then crashed when it hit the next AsyncTask - which needs stuff set up in the first one! I need the app to stop here and load stuff, while showing a ProgressDialog so the user knows why it's stopped, and then carry on

Comment: Try using Thread.sleep(2000) instead of your whole DB/Location code before runOnUIThread()? If that works for you then we have might have some non-wanted interactions between your code and the UI thread which somehow block the progress dialog from being shown.

Comment: Nope that didn't work.  I put log statements in before and after the Thread.sleep(2000) so I could see it being executed, but the screen was just blank - tested on both an emulator and my HTC Wildfire S

Comment: Which Android version are you using? Another idea would be to move the code to onResume(), i.e. later into the lifecycle of your activity. The activity is not really visible yet in onCreate, see the lifecycle (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Comment: I tested the thread (just with sleeping) in onStart and it worked!  There was some code I needed to run in onCreate that I wanted the ProgressDialog for - I'm going to rework it to run later so I can show the ProgressDialog when it runs.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this and report back

```
ProgressDialog dialog;
Context mContext = this;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.shell);
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, getString(R.string.loadingtitle), getString(R.string.loading), true, false);
                }                   
            });
            if(dbHelper == null)
                dbHelper = new WhereWolfOpenHelper(getApplicationContext());                    
            checkUserDetails();
            String providers = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
            checkLocationProviders(providers);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }                   
            });     
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it introduced a new problem: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`.  I believe this is because the `checkUserDetails()` method wants to create a `Dialog` (it doesn't always do this, as it depends on the DB query, so this may have been an existing problem that has just shown...)

Comment: try to add Looper.prerpare() at the beginning of the run